# how to set value from database in Zend Framework 2 in add form element

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

i new to zenframework 2. i have correctly set up zendframework 2,doctrine and zfcUser.All work correctly.

my issue now is now regarding how to prepoulated a form if a member is already logged in.

this is where i extend zfcUser to obtain the Id of a loggged in member:

```
public function setid( $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }


    public function getId()
    {
        if (!$this->id) {
            $this->setid($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->getIdentity()->getId());
        }
        return $this->id;
    }
```

i know want to use that Id to obtain the values from the database and then populate the form with those values.

this is my form:

```
public function aboutYouAction()
    {

        $id  = $this->getId() ;

         $form = new CreateAboutYouForm($this->getEntityManager());
         $aboutYou = new AboutYou();
         $form->setInputFilter($aboutYou->getInputFilter());
         $form->bind($aboutYou);

          if ($this->request->isPost())
          {
            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                 $post  =  $this->request->getPost();
                 $this->getEntityManager()->persist($aboutYou);
                 $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('worker', array('action' =>    'aboutYou')); 

             }

          }

          $messages='';


     //    return array('form' => $form);
         return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'messages' => $messages));
    }
```

Comment: Especially when starting a new Framework it is of crucial important to get [familiar with the official Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#binding-an-object). In this case i've linked you to the specific section.

Comment: why dont you just use $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->getIdentity(); to get the user object and then give it to the form? having the entity manager service in your form and performing query's seems fishy.

Comment: hi. i got the refeence re Service manager from this example: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#the-controllers

Answer (score 0):

To set the values on the form all you need to do is `$form->bind($aboutYou)`

The `bind()` method is designed to take the passed entity instance and map it to the forms elements; This process being referred to as form *hydration*.

Depending on the hydrator attached to the form or fieldset (With doctrine this would normally be the `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject`) this should be able to evaluate the `AboutYou` fields, including any entity references/associations, and set the corresponding form elements values. I'm assuming that one of these fields is `user`.

In you specific case it seems you are binding a new entity (which therefore will not have any properties set, such as your user)

```
$aboutYou = new AboutYou(); // Brand new entity
$form->bind($aboutYou);     // Binding to the form without any data
```

What this means is that the form is trying to set the values of the elements but the provided `AboutYou` class has no data to set (as its new and was not loaded via doctrine) and/or the properties of the `AboutYou` class to not correctly map to the form's elements.

If you wish to bind the user you will need to fetch the *populated* instance. This can be done using doctrine (`$objectManager->find('AboutYou', $aboutYouId)`) or if you need to set  the current logged in user call the controller plugin `ZfcUser\Controller\Plugin\ZfcUserAuthentication` **from within the controller and no where else**.

You workflow should be similar to this (**illustration purposes only**)

```
// Controller
public function aboutYouAction() 
{
  // Get the id via posted/query/route params
  $aboutYouId = $this->params('id', false); 

  // get the object manager
  $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ObjectManager'); 

  // Fetch the populated instance
  $aboutYou = $objectManager->find('AboutYou', $aboutYouId); 

  // here the about you entity should be populated with a user object
  // so that if you were to call $aboutYou->getUser() it would return an user object       

  // Get the form from the service manager (rather than creating it in the controller)
  // meaning you should create a factory service for this
  $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyForm'); 

  // Bind the populated object to the form
  $form->bind($aboutYou);

  //... rest of the action such as handle edits etc

}
```

Comment: Hi AlexP, the reason why i did not use the $this->params('id') is that i want to use the form for both update and for a fresh application. i.e if a person is not logged in then its a fresh form, but if a person is logged in then the form should work as an update

Comment: Conceptually they are two different actions `createAction` and `editAction`. `EditAction` you read the `id` from the route (or via `ZfcUserAuthentication` if its the current user) and `createAction` you just render the form as is. You can still reuse the functionality between forms by using fieldsets. If you add all your current form elements to `UserFieldset` and then attach this fieldset to two different forms `editUserForm` and `createUserForm`.